# How to add a subquery to a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to add a subquery to the query to display the last message in the room?

Chat rooms

```
id, type(USER_TO_USER, USER_TO_SHOP, USER_TO_PLATFORM), name
```

list of messages

```
room_messages - id, participant_id, text, is_read
```

my query

```
select r.id, r.name from rooms as r
left join room_participants rp on r.id = rp.room_id
where rp."participantType" = 'USER' and rp.participant_id = 1
```

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. If you want true LEFT JOIN result, move the rp conditions from WHERE to ON. (And if you want INNER JOIN result, do an INNER JOIN - for clarity's sake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the last message of each room, then join the rest tables:

```
SELECT r.id
      ,r.type
      ,r.name
      ,rm.text
FROM rooms r
INNER JOIN 
(
      SELECT participant_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
      FROM room_messages 
      GROUP BY participant_id
) rm_max 
    ON rm.id = rm_max.participant_id 
INNER JOIN room_messages rm
    ON r.id = rm.participant_id
    AND rm_max.max_id = rm.id
ORDER BY rm.chat_room_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked a little

```
SELECT r.id
      ,r.type
      ,r.name
      ,rm.text
      ,rmf.file
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN room_participants rp
    on r.id = rp.room_id
INNER JOIN
(
      SELECT room_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
      FROM room_messages
      GROUP BY room_id
) rm_max
    ON r.id = rm_max.room_id
INNER JOIN room_messages rm
    ON r.id = rm.room_id AND rm_max.max_id = rm.id
LEFT JOIN room_message_files rmf
    ON rm.id = rmf.room_message_id
where rp."participantType" = 'USER' and rp.participant_id = 1
ORDER BY rm.room_id;
```